# iTunes: The song could not be used because the original file could not be found. Would you like to locate it?

Tags: itunes, apple-music

I've deleted cached Apple Music files as I've needed to free up some space on my Mac.

Now whenever I try to play a previously cached (and deleted) song from Apple Music, I get the following error:

[image]

When I click Cancel, it starts playing normally (starts streaming as if it wasn't cached before), though I get the same error for every single song that have been previously cached.

How can I make iTunes understand that none of those songs are there on disk and need to be downloaded on demand?

Comment: What exactly did you delete. I didn't think that iTunes cached songs.

Comment: @Mark it does. just go to `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Apple Music` folder. Almost all the played Apple Music songs are there.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried consolidating the files? Go to "File" -> "Library" -> "Organize Library" -> "Consolidate files". Afterwards iTunes should know that none of those songs are on your disk.

Comment: Consolidate files option is grayed out.